# Как отправить файл на конкретный виртуальный принтер?

Tags: php, печать

Как на php отправить данные на конкретный виртуальный принтер, установленный на сервере, наплевав на выбор принтера по умолчанию, и задать конкретный пусть сохранения pdf-файла? И как лучше сгенерить имя файла? Задача: посетитель сайта заполнил форму и нажал кнопку «отправить», требуется распечатать эту форму в pdf файл в определённом каталоге под именем, которого ещё нет в данном каталоге, причём, на сервере есть и локальный пользователь, который тоже может что-то послать на печать, при этом для него принтером по умолчанию должен быть один из реальных принтеров.